# Custom Module in Magento 2 : Invalid template file error

Tags: magento2

I am making a form in front end in Magento 2 but sucked in this error anyone can please help me.
Below are my codes:

> in **app/code/My/Module/Block/Contact.php**

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Block;

class Contact extends \Magneto\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
/**
 * Construct
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
)
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

/**
 * Get form action URL for POST booking request
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFormAction()
{
        // companymodule is given in routes.xml
        // controller_name is folder name inside controller folder
        // action is php file name inside above controller_name folder

    return '/mymodule/index/contact';
    // here controller_name is index, action is booking
}
}
```

> in app/code/My/Module/Controller/index/Contact.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Contact extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

/**
 * Contact action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    // 1. POST request : Get contact data
    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    if (!empty($post)) {
        // Retrieve your form data
        $firstname   = $post['firstname'];
        $lastname    = $post['lastname'];
        $phone       = $post['phone'];
        $email = $post['email'];

        // Doing-something with...

        // Display the succes form validation message
        $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage('Submmition done !');

        // Redirect to your form page (or anywhere you want...)
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl('/mymodule/index/stream_context_create()');

        return $resultRedirect;
    }
    // 2. GET request : Render the contact page 
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
}
```

> in app/code/My/Module/etc/frontend/route.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                                                               xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
        <module name="My_Module"/>
    </route>
</router>
</config>
```

> in app/code/My/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="My_Module" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

> in app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/layout/mymodule_index_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout /etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>HTML title - The contact form page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="My\Module\Block\Contact" name="mymodule_contact"  template="My_Module::contact.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

> in app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/templates/contact.phtml

```
<h1>Contact page</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post">
<input name="firstname" type="text">
<input name="lastname" type="text">
<input name="phone" type="text">
<input name="email" type="email">
<input type="submit" value="Send contact informations">
</form>
```

> in app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'My_Module',
__DIR__
);
```

And the errors in the Browser are:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file:    'My_Module::contact.phtml' in module: 'My_Module' block's name: 'mymodule_contact'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file:   'My_Module::contact.phtml' in module: 'My_Module' block's name: 'mymodule_contact'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [lib/internal  /Magento/Framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:668]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:533]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at  [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:585]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:535]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:206]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:488]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:193]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout.php:954]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:494]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php:258]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:130]
#48 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View.php:221]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\View->renderLayout() called at [app/code/My/Module/Controller/Index/Contact.php:40]
#50 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact->execute() called at [generated/code/My/Module/Controller/Index/Contact/Interceptor.php:24]
#51 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact\Interceptor->execute() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#52 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento /Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#53 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#54 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#55 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/My/Module/Controller/Index/Contact/Interceptor.php:39]
#56 My\Module\Controller\Index\Contact\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#57 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#58 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#59 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#60 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]
#61 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#62 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#63 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#64 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#65 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#66 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php:136]
#67 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#68 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php:258]
#69 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
```

Comment: which Magento version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **contact.phtml** file should be inside **`view/frontend/templates`** directory but you have created **`templets`** directory instead of **`templates.`**

Please check the spelling of the templates directory.
It  should be inside **`app/code/My/Module/view/frontend/templates/contact.phtml`**